# Angular 2 switch between versions of components

Tags: angular

I would like to give components a version number, so I can use the same component of different versions in my application.

To illustrate what I mean:
There is a component called  with version 1. I made some improvements on it, so it became version 2. Now in my application I want to use both versions of this component, because the version 1 has features which are still needed, but version 2 doesn't have.

Comment: why not create a new component and use `*ngIf` to control which component to render? Basically you could break your existing component into separate blocks.

Comment: yeah, most nicely is to define in separated components and use below `<router-outlet>` `*ngIF`'s to make your logic